# Ajax/fetch response truncated

Tags: javascript, fetch

Wanted to get the comics from the gocomics.com home page for my personal chrome extension and before I even get to the next step, I hit a road block.

The response I get is cut off (when inspecting the variable from the debbuger), but if I console.log the same variable, I get the full html of the page and then on the next line I pass the same response variable to the function and it is still cut off as you can see in the gif below.
https://s2.gifyu.com/images/aad3e5d9985ee0f3f4.gif

I was first working with xhr when the issue appeared and then tried using fetch and had the same issue.

Here is the code

```
fetch('https://www.gocomics.com/')
.then(function(res) {
  return res.text()
})
.then(function(html) {
  console.log(html)
  parseComicList(html)
})
```

Am I missing something?

To be clear, I am not asking why it is truncated in the debugger, I am asking why the html variable console.logs as the whole document/response, but passed to the function truncated resulting in function not working?

**UPDATE**
Extension needs to:

- Get the page html
- Pass html to parseComicList function

The sole purpose of the parseComicList function is to find comic image url in the html, construct the html with the comic image, move to the next image and repeat until there are no more images and return resulting html, but I didn't do much work with it because it never entered the while loop and I was fiddling with that problem.

Thank you!

Comment: if you console.log inside parseComicList method do you see the entire string ?

Comment: The code above is just fine. There must be a side effect somewhere else, but not in the code you posted above. Can you share more relevant parts of your code? Did you try putting a console.log in the first line of the `parseComicList` function?

Comment: @MadhawaPriyashantha Yes, I see the entire string and when I do if indexOf("string Iam searching") in parseComicList, it returns me -1 even though it console.logs the entire string, confusing

Comment: @fmoliveira I did console.log in the first line of parseComicList for length and to see the content of the response. Both are as it should be, but again indexOf returns -1. I don't have any relevant code, but I updated the question with the inner workings of parseComicList.

Comment: Understood. What string are you searching with `indexOf` that returns -1? I will give it a try here to help you out.

Comment: @fmoliveira I am searching for img-fluid lazyloaded. Thank you for using your time to help me.

Comment: Happy to help! See my answer below. Good luck with the extension, it looks pretty cool! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your fetched html is just fine. The problem is in your `parseComicList` function because it's looking for a class name that doesn't exist in the scraped html code. Let me explain what's happening.

When you load www.gocomics.com in your browser and inspect the html, there are a few img tags with the class names `img-fluid lazyloaded` that you're looking for, and others with the class names `lazyload img-fluid`. Scroll a little bit, and inspect the html again. You'll notice that the img tags with the classnames `lazyload img-fluid` changed to `img-fluid lazyloaded`. See the screenshot below:

[image: class names change while you scroll]

This is a behaviour used by this site to tell whether an image is pending to lazy load or not, which is handled internally with JavaScript as you scroll through the site. This type of lazy load script generally checks if an image is in the viewport or close to entering the viewport, and this is done by comparing the scroll position with the image position. Only then the `lazyload img-fluid` class names change to `img-fluid lazyloaded`.

Your fetch call only downloads the html page of that page, but there is no browser interaction with that code, that is, no scrolling. It means that, based on my observations on how the class names of this site to work while your scroll, you will not find any images with the class names `img-fluid lazyloaded`.

Do `html.indexOf('lazyload img-fluid')` instead, to search for images with the initial class name, and it will work. See the example below:

[image: finding images with the initial class name]

Another hint that won't expose you to the lazy loading logic of the site is looking for ancestor tags with static class names, such as `comic__image` or `item-comic-image`, and then, finding the first img tag immediately after that position. This may be better in some cases because it will help you make sure that you only match images inside posts, instead of matching any lazy loading images of the site. In this case, it starts skipping the first img which is inside the top banner. See the example below:

[image: alternatively looking for ancestor tags with static class names]

Comment: Yes, I pasted the response in the text file from the console.log and saw the class name is different than in the browser just like you said. I should've choose static class name instead. Thank you for your time and help and for an explanation.

Answer (score 0):

IN your gif it only shows that debugger is showing truncated value, can you check the length of string inside parseComicsList function and before doing console.log ?

You can check its value in scope section, it has full length up to last closing tag

[image]

Comment: I checked the length of the string and it is the same.
Everywhere in the debugger is the entire string except when I mouseover the response variable (ok, given the limited space, it is understandable why it is cut off), but I don't understand why it is cut off when I passed it to a function.

Comment: Can you check the length in the called function as well? Is it truncacted there too?

Comment: Length is ok and response doesn't seem to be truncated there, but it still doesn't work.

Comment: If the length is ok, and your function is getting the desired input, then 
A. You now know that values don't change just because they are passed to another function unless you do it intentionally or a bug is there
B. Your original question is solved.

So, please mark the answer as resolved and do a little debugging what else is failing and ask question about it if you still cannot solve it. Happy Debugging!

Comment: Browser interaction changed the class name, it differed from the response fetch got and that is why it didn't work. Thank you for your time.

Answer (score -1):

You are sending a GET request. It's doing as expected - it's returning you the HTML of the page. If you want to do a POST request, it has to be in the form

```
 fetch("server.com/potatoes", {
    method: "POST",
    headers: {
      Accept: "application/json",
      "Content-type": "application/json",
    },
  })
    .then(res => {
      return res.json();
    })
    .then(res => {
      console.log(res);
    })
    .catch(e => {
      console.log(e);
    });
```

Headers are not required and if you do not include them, they will be automatically added. They need to be changed, depending on what kind of response you are expecting.